# marginal conditional from joint of three r.v.'s

Tags: joint-distribution, conditional-expectation, marginal-distribution, exponential-family

I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. I know that $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$ and $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(c,d)$. Furthermore, I know that $Z \sim \text{Poisson}(XY)$.

I know the joint distribution factorises as $P(X,Y,Z) = P(Z|XY)P(X|a,b) P(Y|c,d)$.

I would like to find the mean of the marginal distribution of $X$ given that $Z$ is known. I am not sure whether or not this is possible because of the way $X$ and $Y$ are coupled together in the Poisson mean. Ideally I would just like a yes/no as to whether I am wasting my time!

The marginal $P(X)$ is itself not that hard to find after I rewrite all the Y terms into a new Gamma distribution. The problem is when I try to calculate $E[X] = \int x P(X=x)$, there is no easy way to write it into an exponential family form due to a term that appears from the marginalisation of $Y$. This makes me think the calculation is not possible....

Comment: When you write $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$, you have already told us what $P(X)$ is. Why do you need to find "the marginal $P(X)$" all over again? Isn't it just the $\text{Gamma}(a,b)$ distribution? or is $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$ a conditional distribution of $X$, including, as a special case if you are a frequentist, conditional on unknown parameters $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$ writes like
$$p(x,y,z)\propto x^{a-1}\exp\{-bx\}\,y^{c-1}\exp\{-dy\}\,(xy)^z\exp\{-xy\}/z!$$
the conditional of $(X,Y)$ given $Z=z$ is
$$p(x,y|z)\propto x^{a-1}\exp\{-bx\}\,y^{c-1}\exp\{-dy\}\,(xy)^z\exp\{-xy\}$$
and the marginal conditional of $X$ given $Z=z$ is
\begin{align}p(x,y|z)&\propto \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}\exp\{-bx\}\,y^{c-1}\exp\{-dy\}\,(xy)^z\exp\{-xy\}\,\text{d}y\\
&\propto x^{z+a-1}\exp\{-bx\}\,\int_0^\infty y^{c-1}\exp\{-dy-xy\}\,y^z\,\text{d}y\\
&\propto x^{z+a-1}\exp\{-bx\}\,(d+x)^{-c-z}\end{align}
The conditional mean of $X$ given $Z=z$ is thus
$$\mathbb E[X|Z=z] = \dfrac{\int_0^\infty  x^{z+a}\exp\{-bx\}\,(d+x)^{-c-z}\,\text{d}x}{\int_0^\infty x^{z+a-1}\exp\{-bx\}\,(d+x)^{-c-z}\,\text{d}x}$$
I do not know if there exist nice representations of this ratio of integrals. My copy of [Gradsteyn & Ryzhik](https://archive.org/details/GradshteinI.S.RyzhikI.M.TablesOfIntegralsSeriesAndProducts/mode/2up/search/exponential+rational+fraction) is at the office but, checking it online, it sounds like **3.353** (p.341) is the closest and not particularly helpful identity.